# Values in OpportunitiesHistory do not seem to be there

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, opportunity-history

My test does:

```
Opportunity opp2 = opps.get(1);
opp2.probability = 40;
upsert(opp2);

opp2.probability = 30;
upsert(opp2);

System.debug('****opp2History=' + opp2.OpportunityHistories);
```

I was expecting OpportunityHistories to have some values but it is blank, since I have changed the Opportunity.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the database to see such changes ;)

`System.debug([SELECT Id, Name FROM OpportunityHistory WHERE OpportunityId = :opp2.Id]);` for a start?

I'm not sure if it will work in an unit test though (should work if you have a normal Apex Script with Execute Anonymous)... from what I remember field history tracking changes are written only when transaction actually commits and tests never commit to the database...

Comment: correct. OpportunityHistory never updated in database in test. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why do you need the history values? It's a standard functionality, doesn't make much sense to check if the history really was written. If your update would fail on some trigger - you'd know because you'd get an exception. If you're afraid some workflow has overwritten the values - query the Probability from DB and assert that they're equal...

Comment: I have some business logic based on the OpportunityHistory and I want to test it.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to mock it then - create a fake `List<OpportunityHistory> fakeResults` variable and then `if(Test.isRunningTest()){ /* use fakeResults */ } else { /* not in unit tests so query for the real data */ }`. You don't even have to insert them (and probably it'd fail if you'd try it).

Comment: thanks but that approach is limited because OpportunityHistory fields are not writable. So you'd have to create a wrapper around it which is so messy. Think it just won't get tested.